# How do I enable through-the-filesystem diazo editing with plone 4.3

Tags: plone, diazo, plone-4.x

Summary: through-the-filesystem editing not working for my diazo theme. Plone breaks.

Details:
I've created my first live plone site with 4.3.2 and diazo. You can see the live version at [borogreen.org](http://borogreen.org). I would like to keep editing the theme forward.

My ubuntu 12.04LTS test server has only plone432 + diazo + dexterity (not used) + Static resource storage 1.0.2 enabled. For test purposes, I'm using the available sunrain theme.

I've placed the sunrain theme manually inside the /resources folder, as suggested per 
http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.theming/userguide.html#deploying-and-testing-themes

Trying to enable that theme in the Site Setup | Theming panel | Advanced, I set the path to the theme rules to

```
/++theme++sunrain/rules.xml
```

and the absolute path prefix to

```
/++theme++sunrain/
```

Plone does not recognize it: no theme gets enabled. The debug mode spits out the following error codes

```
2014-03-29 00:10:07 ERROR plone.subrequest Error handling subrequest to /++theme++sunrain/rules.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.subrequest-1.6.7-py2.7.egg/plone/subrequest/__init__.py", line 116, in subrequest
traversed = request.traverse(path)
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py", line 502, in traverse
subobject = self.traverseName(object, entry_name)
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py", line 326, in traverseName
ob2 = namespaceLookup(ns, nm, ob, self)
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.traversing-3.13.2-py2.7.egg/zope/traversing/namespace.py", line 112, in namespaceLookup
return traverser.traverse(name, ())
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.resource-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/plone/resource/traversal.py", line 27, in traverse
raise NotFound
NotFound
2014-03-29 00:10:07 ERROR plone.transformchain Unexpected error whilst trying to apply transform chain
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.transformchain-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/plone/transformchain/transformer.py", line 48, in __call__
newResult = handler.transformIterable(result, encoding)
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/plone/app/theming/transform.py", line 170, in transformIterable
transform = self.setupTransform(runtrace=runtrace)
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/plone/app/theming/transform.py", line 108, in setupTransform
transform = compileThemeTransform(rules, absolutePrefix, readNetwork, parameterExpressions, runtrace=runtrace)
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/plone/app/theming/utils.py", line 580, in compileThemeTransform
runtrace=runtrace,
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/diazo-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/diazo/compiler.py", line 115, in compile_theme
read_network=read_network,
File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/diazo-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/diazo/rules.py", line 195, in process_rules
rules_doc = etree.parse(rules, parser=rules_parser)
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2957, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:56299)
File "parser.pxi", line 1526, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82331)
File "parser.pxi", line 1555, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82624)
File "parser.pxi", line 1455, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81663)
File "parser.pxi", line 1002, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78623)
File "parser.pxi", line 569, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74567)
File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75458)
File "parser.pxi", line 588, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74760)
IOError: Error reading file '/++theme++sunrain/rules.xml': failed to load external entity "/++theme++sunrain/rules.xml"
```

What's wrong here?

ps: of course I can upload the theme as zip file and enable it that way, which works fine. I would really like to edit through-the-filesystem as I can foresee a lot of development in the future.

An up-to-date and working write-up for plone432 how to edit diazo themes through the filesystem using the /resources directory would be the answer, but I have not found that either outside of the plone.app.theming user guide. Help!

Comment: I know there's the write-up by Anderson Leeb at http://andersonleeb.com/blog/plone.app.theming-in-5-minutes. This mentions a Basic Settings option in the Theming panel that I have seen in a prior plone version <4.3, but no longer in 432: [x] Enable Theme
Select A Theme -> My theme (my.theme)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472811/new-theme-product-gives-valueerror-theme-my-theme-is-not-available/23477716#23477716