# New theme product gives "ValueError: Theme my.theme is not available"

Tags: plone, diazo

I have created a new theme via zopeskel using these instructions
http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/theme_product_with_diazo.html

However trying to install the product, I get the error:

```
Module plone.app.theming.exportimport.handler, line 38, in importTheme
ValueError: Theme hccrems.theme is not available
```

I'm not sure what my theme is missing as I have followed through the doc twice.

src/hccrems.theme/hccrems/theme/configure.zcml
http://pastie.org/9142461

src/hccrems.theme/hccrems/theme/profiles/default/theme.xml
http://pastie.org/9142470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create an egg with the **diazotheme**-template of zopeskel:

  `zopeskel diazotheme your.theme`
- Add `theme.xml` in profiles/default with the content according to the docs you pointed to.
- In `your.theme/your/theme/configure.zcml` remove the z3c.jbot-part, unless you want to use it, then you'll need to add z3c.jbot as a dep and include the documentated meta.zcml-slug in your configure.zcml.
- Remove everything in your.theme/your/theme/diazo_resources and bump your static-files (possbibly exported of an online-generated theme) in it.

Comment: Holy zopeskel's doing (almost) everything for us, the error should not appear, after this recipe.

Comment: should i update the doc to say "zopeskel diazotheme your.theme"?

Comment: That'll be awesome. Please then also mark the z3c.jbot-part as optional. I _think_ it's not part of our official stack, but you might want to doublecheck that.

Comment: Where do you get the diazotheme-template from? `ERROR: No such template: diazotheme`

Comment: Oh, it's in a [separate package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopeskel.diazotheme/1.1).

Answer (score 1):

configure.zcml should not be in the src/hccrems.theme/hccrems/theme/profiles directory, it should be in the src/hccrems.theme/hccrems/theme directory.

Is that a mistake in your question? Or is that how the theme was generated? If so, that is a bug.

Also, please provide a complete traceback.

Comment: That was a mistake in the question. Here's the traceback: http://pastie.org/9143945#